# A hologram is offset in a screenshot

Tags: vuforia, hololens

I use Vuforia to recognize a tag and put a hologram above it. I want to take a screenshot with that. But the hologram is displayed in the wrong place on the screenshot, although I see it in the right place through HoloLens.

What is the reason? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the camera is not in the center of the HoloLens but, rather it is over the right eye. Therefore any pictures you take with the HoloLens will be slightly offset.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Mixed Reality Capture (MRC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/mixed-reality-capture-overview), for good alignment you have to make sure that the focus plane is set at the hologram depth as discussed in the link above. Here is some information on how to set it in Unity https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/focus-point-in-unity